# SOAP WebService: soapenv:Server.userExceptionorg.xml.sax.SAXException: Bad envelope tag: definitions

Tags: soap, postman

I am trying to access my SOAP Service from POSTMAN but when I am providing SOAPAction as "" in the header and sending the request it displays "SOAP WebService: soapenv:Server.userExceptionorg.xml.sax.SAXException: Bad envelope tag: definitions".

Can anyone let me know about this error and its cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the solution for this query as I was not sending the proper envelope in the body of my request.